# How to generate new event to attendee's outlook calendar who previously declined that event?

Tags: android, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-calendar

We are using [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for creating events in the outlook calendar using Android.

> The event is permanently removed from the outlook calendar when the attendee declined that event.

So we need to regenerate that event to that particular attendee's calendar without updating any other changes by the organizer (just add another attendee).

**For example,**

Abc is Organizer
A1 is Attendees

now A1 declined that event. Then the organizer updates the event by adding only another attendee(A2) (Not made any other changes like summary, dates, timezone, location, etc...) just added another attendee.

In this case, Microsoft(Outlook) does not recreate the event on that specific attendee's calendar.

One solution is that we first removed that specific attendee by updating the event and then again add that attendee. so the event regenerates to that specific attendee's outlook calendar.
but it might become a lengthy process.

so Are there any other ways to recreate an event in a specific attendee calendar who previously declined the event?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other ways to recreate an event in a specific attendee calendar who previously declined the event?

No, you need to send a new meeting request by adding an attendee anew.